# Show that integral of f over γ is equal to F(b)-F(a) on the complex plane

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

Let $f$ be continuous on an open connected subset $Ω$ and let $f = F'$ on $Ω$.

Let $γ$ be a smooth curve in $Ω$ with $γ(0) = a$ and $γ(1) = b$, prove that $$\int_γ f \;\mathrm{dz}=F(b)-F(a)$$

Comment: Write down the definition of $\int_{\gamma} f \, dz$ and see what you get.

Comment: As Murthy said, use the definition of $\int_{\gamma}f\text{d}z$. Then replace $f$ with $F^{\prime}$, and you will see that you are taking the antiderivative of something that has had the chain rule applied to it.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy have no definition. The entire question is what I wrote above.

Comment: @Jake have no definition. The entire question is what I wrote above.

Comment: @MohamadMoustafa you don't need an explicit definition of $\gamma$. You should know that $\gamma$ is just some contour connecting $a$ and $b$. You can convert your integral to have the lower-bound as the beginning of $\gamma$'s domain and the upper-bound as the end of $\gamma$'s domain, which are $0$ and $1$ respectively in this case.

Comment: @Jake wont that give me F(1)-F(0)?

Comment: It will give you $F\left(\gamma\left(1\right)\right)-F\left(\gamma\left(0\right)\right)$.

Comment: @Jake so is the rule that "integral over gamma of f" is "integral over beginning and end of domain of gamma of f(gamma)"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a parametrization of $\gamma$. Then by definition $$\int_\gamma f dz = \int_0^1 f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt$$
Now try to calculate the derivative of $F(\gamma(t))$. Do you see how you can use that to solve the integral?

Comment: For the RHS of the equation you wrote, how to evaluate derivative(gamma(t))dt? I saw this rule before but I cant understand the RHS.

Comment: We don't need to evaluate the derivative of $\gamma(t)$. We can't because we don't know what $\gamma$ is. Have you tried applying the chain rule to $F(\gamma(t))'$? Do you see how you can use that remove the $\gamma'(t)$ from the integral?

Comment: Yes, I finally get it. Thank you